# How to use OpenTelemetry processor to parse information in body.str attribute of the logs?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm new to the OpenTelemetry project and I'm testing it out on a small Kubernetes cluster to process some logs using a `filelogprocessor`. Using the [attributesprocessor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/attributesprocessor/README.md) I can manipulate attributes from the log that begin with the `attributes` keyword by hashing the value, deleting, inserting etc. I can do the same with the [resourceattributes](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/resourceprocessor/README.md) processor An example of what I have in my helm values for the hashing is this:

```
processors:
  attributes/example:
    actions:
    - key: log.file.path
      action: hash
    - key: time
      action: hash
  resource:
    attributes:
    - key: k8s.container.name
      action: hash
```

```
attributes.environment                          prod    
attributes.log.file.path                        0ae05f2b5c9771153b3e4861cc78f670e8697804    
attributes.log.iostream                         stdout
attributes.time                                 9fd07c1b865b5c945ac1c3a4d14a4457dab037dc
```

However, my logs come with a `body.str` field that I assume couldn't be parsed by the processors and I couldn't figure out any other processor useful to manipulate the information in that field.

Is there any way that I can perform operation in the data contained in the `body.str` say, for example, drop a log that has a given value for `entryPointName` in the `body.str`?

This is an example of what the `body.str` of the log looks like

```
body.str    {
  ClientHost:            '10.1.0.33',
  ClientPort:            '47470',
  ClientUsername:        '-',
  DownstreamContentSize: 2,
  DownstreamStatus:      200,
  OriginContentSize:     2,
  OriginDuration:        15843,
  OriginStatus:          200,
  Overhead:              40472,
  RequestAddr:           '10.1.0.36:9000',
  RequestContentSize:    0,
  RequestHost:           '10.1.0.36',
  RequestMethod:         'GET',
  RequestPath:           '/ping',
  RequestPort:           '9000',
  RequestProtocol:       'HTTP/1.1',
  RequestScheme:         'http',
  RetryAttempts:         0,
  RouterName:            'ping@internal',
  StartUTC:              '2023-07-03T14:08:26.980876844Z',
  entryPointName:        'traefik',
  level:                 'info',
  msg:                   '',
  time:                  '2023-07-03T14:08:26Z',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several processors support a common language called OpenTelemetry Transformation Language (OTTL) which allows you to refer to various elements of telemetry using a path expression. For logs, the possible paths are described [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/4874893a9395618fa7a19e9c7471047ae8680fe7/pkg/ottl/contexts/ottllog#paths).

For the specific example of dropping a log that contains a given value in the `entryPointName` field, you could use the [`filter` processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/filterprocessor/README.md#examples).

```
processors:
  filter:
    logs:
      log_record:
        - 'IsMatch(body["str"]["entryPointName"], "traefik")'
```

The [`transform` processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/transformprocessor/README.md) also uses OTTL and may be useful for many other types of manipulations.